# how to install apps onto windows phone via sd card

Tags: 8.0, apps, micro-sd

I have tried out the guide given on the official windows phone site and looked into various question posted on this site for that matter, however I'm still failing to do an offline install of windows app via the SD card.

As instructed, I downloaded the xap files from the online store onto my flash drive. Then placed the xap files on the root of the SD Card via Windows Explorer, i.e. after  connecting the phone to the PC and doing the old cut and paste.

I did as instructed howeever I still cannot see an SD card option on my Apps> Store.
The website suggested that App>Store takes a while to show the SD card option, I placed the xap files last night. Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research, it seems that the apps, on the SD card,are not detected by the phone unless it is rebooted. I don't know whether this is a glitch or all Windows 8 phones work this way. All I did was the following:

1. Insert SD card on Phone
2. Format the SD card from Phone (optional)
3. Connect to PC
4. Paste all the apps on the root of the SD card.
5. Restart phone
6. Goto Apps> Store
7. the SD card option is now visible
8. Select the SD Card option to see the apps

Some guys also posted that they had to remove and reinsert the SD card for the apps to be detected.

---

### EDIT

An active internet connection is still required to install the apps on phone.