# Process to install local application in windows Lumia 535

Tags: apps

I have XAP file but I am unable to install that application locally in Microsoft Lumia 535 please assist me by some process or by some application that would help me to install application directly without downloading from Store.

Thanks

Comment: You could find the answer you are looking for in here: [how to install apps onto windows phone via sd card](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/how-to-install-apps-onto-windows-phone-via-sd-card)

Comment: Please mention where you downloaded that xap, is it patched or original?